# How exactly does =[Me] work?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I've read that in 2010, using '[volatile columns](http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/)', like [Me], isn't encouraged. Though this functionality is needed as a default value for a column separate of Created By or Modified By.

However, when =Me is put into the default value, it gives the Claim and not the display name. Does anyone know how =Me is used by SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

I've always seen that as a hack method to get the UI to do something. You could always use a workflow to do the calculation and then update the field with that calculated value.

When you try to use Me in a calculated column, it grabs the account name. In every instance I've used it, it has always been domain\account, but if it is showing a claim I am assume you are using claims based auth.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Claims. It's not in a calculated column per se, it's more in a default value of a Free Text column (so the user can change it if they want to).